# Deserialize json with xml string columns in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I want to deserialize this json:

```
    [{"BuyPrice":0,"Description":null,"Id":3,"ReceptionId":7,"RejectPart":"
<Rejectedparameters>\u000d\u000a  <OutsideState>0<\/OutsideState>\u000d\u000a 
 <FastRPM>0<\/FastRPM>\u000d\u000a  <IdleRPM>0<\/IdleRPM>\u000d\u000a  
<FastLambda>0<\/FastLambda>\u000d\u000a  <FastCO>0<\/FastCO>\u000d\u000a  
<BackBrake>0<\/BackBrake>\u000d\u000a  <HandBrake>0<\/HandBrake>\u000d\u000a 
 <FrontBrake>0<\/FrontBrake>\u000d\u000a  
<BackLeftShockAbsorber>0<\/BackLeftShockAbsorber>\u000d\u000a  
<BackRightShockAbsorber>0<\/BackRightShockAbsorber>\u000d\u000a  
<FrontLeftShockAbsorber>0<\/FrontLeftShockAbsorber>\u000d\u000a  
<FrontRightShockAbsorber>0<\/FrontRightShockAbsorber>\u000d\u000a 
 <HandBrakeAcceleration>0<\/HandBrakeAcceleration>\u000d\u000a  
<BrakeAcceleration>0<\/BrakeAcceleration>\u000d\u000a  
<BackSideSlip>0<\/BackSideSlip>\u000d\u000a  <TotalWeight>0<\/TotalWeight>
\u000d\u000a  <BackWeight>0<\/BackWeight>\u000d\u000a  
<FrontWeight>0<\/FrontWeight>\u000d\u000a  <Lambda>0<\/Lambda>\u000d\u000a  
<NOX>0<\/NOX>\u000d\u000a  <CO2>0<\/CO2>\u000d
\u000a<\/Rejectedparameters>","Result":"Reject","SellPrice":220000,"State":nu
ll,"SubmitDatetime":"\/Date(1499677272213+0430)\/"}]
```

as you can see one of my columns is in XML format.
My code to deserialize this json:

```
string result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/ReceptionHistoryService.svc/ReceptionHistoryByReceptionId/" + id);

var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return javascriptserializer.Deserialize<ReceptionHistory>(result);
```

but I get this error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Additional information: Type 'TRMStartPoint_NoCamera.DataContractModel.ReceptionHistory' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

Here is my receptionhistory class:

```
public class ReceptionHistory
{
    public Int64 Id { set; get; }
    public DateTime SubmitDatetime { set; get; }
    public Int64 ReceptionId { set; get; }
    public Int64 SellPrice { set; get; }
    public Int64 BuyPrice { set; get; }
    public string State { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string RejectPart { set; get; }
    public string Result { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON document is an array, indicated by the square brackets. Deserialize it to a collection

Comment: @SirRufo i added my receptionhistory class .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that your type is not supposed to deserialize an array.
Try to deserialize `List<T>`, instead of `ReceptionHistory`, like this:

```
javascriptserializer.Deserialize<List<ReceptionHistory>>(result);
```